# Can the Wish spell make the effects of an attuned magic item permanent?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

So lets say that a PC has several magic items and he comes across the use of a wish spell. He then wishes to retain all of his magical attributes that he has gained through these items even after he un-attunes to them. How would you all deal with this?

Comment: I've revised the title to summarize the question. Feel free to change it if it doesn't express your intent.

Comment: Your question presents this as a hypothetical situation. Is it really hypothetical, or has one of your players actually asked about this?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You might be able to achieve something beyond the scope of the above examples. State your wish to the DM as precisely as possible. The DM has great latitude in ruling what occurs in such an instance, **the greater the wish, the greater the likelihood that something goes wrong.** **This spell might simply fail, the effect you desire might only be partly achieved, or you might suffer some unforeseen consequence as a result of how you worded the wish.** For example, wishing that a villain were dead might propel you forward in time to a period when that villain is no longer alive, effectively removing you from the game. Similarly, wishing for a legendary magic item or artifact might instantly transport you to the presence of the item's current owner.

This clearly falls in the realms of a “greater” wish.

### So many options!

1. If I was feeling kind, it would simply fail.
2. If I was feeling *really* generous, it might work with one of the items - effectively giving them an additional attunement “slot”.
3. Slightly more nasty would be allowing them to “unattune” from these items and keep their effects but find they are unable to attune to any others. This is probably [the turkey’s a little dry](https://youtu.be/xThh0z5J6zk) option.
4. If they really screw up the wording and I’m feeling particularly malicious, the items might fuse permanently and hideously with their body giving the benefit but causing *Fear* in everyone they meet.

All DMs need to have read W. W. Jacobs [The Monkey’s Paw](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey's_Paw) before adjudicating *Wish*.

Comment: +1 for the monkey's paw reference. But be careful when you monkey's paw not all players will take kindly to having their wish twisted in such a way.

Comment: @Himitsu_no_Yami a copy of the story comes free with every *Wish* in my campaigns - think of it as a users manual.

Comment: That's amazing and I love it. Totally not about to steal your idea for my own games...